# How to update multiple google sheets at once using gspread

Tags: python, json, api, gspread

I'm trying to update multiple google sheets using python and nothing I try seems to work. I want to be able to input data once and have it automatically fill in the same data in another spreadsheet. Here's my code I have so far:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eds76.png

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from `nothing I try seems to work.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, can you add your current script to your question as the text data instead of the image?

Comment: Hi thank you so much for taking the time to answer but I managed to figure it out thankfully

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Hi thank you so much for taking the time to answer but I managed to figure it out thankfully`, I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Hope this helps someone!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbnHm.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).